# How to DRY a Bootstrap view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I'm looking for a better way to effectively DRY my Rails views that use Bootstrap 3.0

Here's the HAML code of the view:

```
%h1 Profiles

.visible-xs
  %table.table.table-striped
    %tbody
      - @profiles.each do |profile|
        %tr
          %td
            = profile.name
          %td{style: "text-align: right"}
            =link_to "<i class='fa fa-eye fa-small'></i>".html_safe, setup_profile_path(profile), class: "btn"
            =link_to "<i class='fa fa-edit fa-small'></i>".html_safe, edit_setup_profile_path(profile), class: "btn"

.hidden-xs
  %table.table
    %tr
      %th Name
      %th Last Updated
      %th Actions
    - @profiles.each do |profile|
      %tr
        %td= profile.name
        %td= time_ago_in_words profile.updated_at
        %td
          =link_to "<i class='fa fa-eye fa-small'></i> Details".html_safe, setup_profile_path(profile), class: "btn btn-sm"
          =link_to "<i class='fa fa-edit fa-small'></i> Change".html_safe, edit_setup_profile_path(profile), class: "btn btn-sm"
          =link_to "<i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-small'></i> Remove".html_safe, setup_profile_path(profile, method: :destroy), class: "btn btn-sm"
```

As you can see, I have an additional column (presently) and may add two or three more for the larger viewports (hence a table layout) as the app develops, but for the mobile devices, I just show the Profile name and buttons to get to more details (which is all that's really practical on small screens).

I tried using rows and cols of the grid system, but its a *lot* of work to get a usable interface at each viewport size and the template code looks like a big ball of mud when all in one.  Separating into XS and "everything else" so far is the cleanest implementation, but two blocks and two loops though same data to present.  Before I go and create 20 more of these, is there a DRY'er way to implement mobile (xs) vs. tablet/desktop (sm, md, lg, ...) viewports that is still very clear to glance at and understand?

Comment: you can have a looks over cells, which helps in refactoring view code

Comment: Could you elaborate.  "a looks over cells" is Greek to me.

Comment: Check this cells.rubyforge.org/